# Could not validate the form using PHP and Stripe payment gateway

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I need to validate the form where I am using Stripe payment gateway recurring payment. My code is below.

```
<form method="post" action="charge.php" name="renew" onsubmit="return validate();">
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package" mode="normal" duration="30" text="1 Monat" value="29.90"> 29.90 € Pro Werbeanzeige-Laufzeit: 1 Monat<br>
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package" mode="normal" duration="60" text="2 Monate" value="49.90"> 49.90 € Pro Werbeanzeige-Laufzeit: 2 Monate<br>
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package" mode="normal" duration="90" text="3 Monate" value="59.90"> 59.90 € Pro Werbeanzeige-Laufzeit: 3 Monate<br>
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package" mode="recurring" duration="30" text="Monate" value="19.90"> 19,90 € Monate<br>
<input name="oid" type="hidden" value="<?=$oid;?>" />
<input name="mode" id="mode" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="duration" id="duration" type="hidden" value="" />
<!--<input type="submit" name="makepayment" value="Pay" > -->
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-name="GOALSTART"
          data-description="1 Monate"
          data-panel-label="Abonnieren"
          data-label="PAY NOW"
          data-locale="auto">></script>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate(){
    console.log('hello');
    if (document.getElementById('package').checked) {
        //alert("checked submit form");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Unchecked form will not be submitted");
        return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here I need if radio button has not checked then the form will not submit. But as per my code it could not check the validation.

Comment: You have multiple elements all with the same ID. IDs are meant to be unique, so when you `getElementById` you only get the first element with that ID found rather than all of them.

Comment: @PaulAsjes:It should first call the validate function.

Comment: That's irrelevant satya, as pointed out, you have duplicate ID's which is not valid. Most clever editors will flag this as a problem. Alongside with the extra / incorrect closing tag '>' after `data-locale`.

Comment: This can be closed as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.

Answer (score 1):

Add a div around the checkout.stripe.com script. Since the "Pay Now" is being dynamically generated and thus you dont have much control over it. So you can restrict clicking on it by following method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="charge.php" name="renew" onsubmit="validate();">
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package-1" mode="normal" duration="30" text="1 Monat" value="29.90" required="true"> 29.90 € Pro Werbeanzeige-Laufzeit: 1 Monat<br>
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package-2" mode="normal" duration="60" text="2 Monate" value="49.90"> 49.90 € Pro Werbeanzeige-Laufzeit: 2 Monate<br>
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package-3" mode="normal" duration="90" text="3 Monate" value="59.90"> 59.90 € Pro Werbeanzeige-Laufzeit: 3 Monate<br>
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package-4" mode="recurring" duration="30" text="Monate" value="19.90"> 19,90 € Monate<br>
<input name="oid" type="hidden" value="<?=$oid;?>" />
<input name="mode" id="mode" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="duration" id="duration" type="hidden" value="" />
<!--<input type="submit" name="makepayment" value="Pay" > -->
<div class="checkout-part-wrapper">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-name="GOALSTART"
          data-description="1 Monate"
          data-panel-label="Abonnieren"
          data-label="PAY NOW"
          data-locale="auto">>
</script>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('.checkout-part-wrapper').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  jQuery('input[type=radio][name=package]').change(function() {
    jQuery('.checkout-part-wrapper').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 although I think it would be better to play by Stripes rules / use an officially supported way of generating a checkout with custom inputs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if (document.getElementById('package').checked) {
```

to

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('input[name=package]:checked').length) {
```

Comment: No that function is not calling at all.

Comment: @satya 
1. The submit button is commented out in the question.
2. onsubmit="return validate();" will call the validate function on form submission.
3. If you cannot see any output, try developer tools and check the console tab after enabling preserve log option (Or simply put alert() function instead of console.log)

Comment: "The submit button is commented out in the question" 
An /alternative/ submit button is commented out, the actual submit button being used is the 'stripe-button' brought in by JS (which incidentally is partly what is causing the headache here).

Comment: mikeyjk Aah!! Thanks! I didn't notice it. 

@satya Did you check this?
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#using-your-own-button

Comment: Np at all - I think you've suggested the right place to look invalid-bot.
That, or: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

This q. isn't PHP at all - this is Stripe + JavaScript.

You don't really want to create your own JS validator without referring to Stripes documentation. There's probably a Stripe guru out there who can clearly show how best to add custom validation. I can't help but wonder whether OP would be better off seeking out some Stripe tutorials / support channels etc.

Comment: @mikeyjk You're right. It is better to check with Stripe documentation. I just pointed out the problem in his javascript code.